# Angular Production Build generating lot of Lazy Chunk Files

Tags: angular, visual-studio, asp.net-core, angular-cli, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm a newbie for angular and currently developing an Angular application which created via Visual Studio and lately updated to the latest Angular Version (12).

My application doesn't have any implementations with lazy loading. But when I'm publishing the application, it is generating tons of js files under a name called **Lazy Chunk Files**.

My build output as follows.
[image]

My tsconfig.json file as follows,

[image]

And, my angular.json file as follows,

```html
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "Website": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "progress": true,
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": ["@ctrl/ngx-codemirror", "xlsx"],
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": ""
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "Website:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "Website:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "Website:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist-server",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json",
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false
          },
          "configurations": {
            "dev": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true
            },
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": ""
        }
      }
    },
    "Website-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "Website:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "Website"
}
```

My app-routing.module.ts file as follows, (Reduced some repeated code lines and imports)

```html
// Imports for the necessary components


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'default' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [LoginGuard] },
  { path: 'logout', component: LogoutComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },

  { path: 'authentication', component: AuthenticationComponent },
  { path: 'dialog-status', component: DialogStatusComponent },
  { path: 'dialog-confirm', component: DialogConfirmComponent },
    // There are some more paths defined for the dialog components in the real file

  { path: 'password', component: ChangePasswordComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'reports', component: ReportsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], canDeactivate: [PendingChangesGuard] },
    // There are some more paths defined for the components in the real file

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

My app-module.ts file as follows, (Reduced some repeated code lines and imports)

```html
// Necessary imports


registerLocaleData(localeEs);


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    // And some more components
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide:  TranslateLoader,
        useClass: CustomLoader,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [
    AppService,
    TranslateService,
    PendingChangesGuard,
    {
      provide: LOCALE_ID,
      useFactory: (appService: AppService) => appService.getLocalLanguage(),
      deps: [AppService]
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  exports: [TranslateModule]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I need to stop generating these **Lazy Chunk Files** when I'm performing a build. Could any of you have any idea about this??

(Please let me know if you need more information)

Comment: You must have all these module setup as lazy loaded module, thats why no other reason. ANgular by default does not create this lazy modules unless you asked for it . Share your routing configuration.

Comment: You should use lazy-loaded modules, it's the recommended approach. If you don't use lazy-loaded modules, your entire angular app is downloaded/loaded in the browser from the point someone visits your website, also the modules (code) that aren't needed at that point. This would have a massive performance hit.

Comment: Vimal Patel - Yeah, I had that thought. But wasn't able to identify the change to stop generating those lazy chunk files. Please check the updated post. Thanks.

Comment: Pieterjan - Your explanation is much appreciated. If so, it is better to use a lazy-loaded modules. But for testing purposes I would like to test the other way as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm answering my own question as I just found the reason for generating those tons of js files.

First I changed the production build configurations settings to generate the chunk files with their names (currently it's just a Guid) by using the following setting,

```
        "namedChunks": true
```

Then the outcome was as follows,
[image]

After seen those names, I realized that these chunk files are from the **angular/common/locals** which I used within my application to enable both Spanish(es) and English(en) languages.

The @angular/common/locals has tons of js language files for all cultures in the world. But in my case I only need the es and en languages. Therefore, I simply deleted those unnecessary js files for other cultures.

Then finally my output was as follows,
[image]

**(Updated)**

If you still getting lots of js lazy chunk files, try deleting the angular cache folder. (ClientApp/.angular)